# Python script printing lines twice

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8

Here is a small 'hackety' script I wrote for work, its printing all the lines it finds twice, why?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

ins = open("FileName")

for line in ins:
    s  = list(line.decode("utf-8"))
    for character in s:
       if ord( character ) > 10000:
          print repr(line)

ins.close()
```

Comment: Because you don't `break` out of the `for` loop after the first `print`? I guess there are two characters with `ord` over 10,000 in those lines.

Comment: Even "hacketier": `import re; print re.findall(u"^.*[\u03e8-\uffff].*", ins.read())` :) (dec 10000 == hex 3e8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a break in your inner loop.

```
for line in ins:
    s  = list(line.decode("utf-8"))
    for character in s:
       if ord( character ) > 10000:
          print repr(line)
          # Found it in the line, move onto the next line
          break
```

Otherwise you'll print a line multiple times if there are multiple matches in a line.

You should use a **with** statement for the file handle.

```
with open("FileName", "r") as ins:
    <do stuff with ins>
```

Also, you don't have to cast the string returned by line.decode() to a list; calling it's iterator is what the list constructor will do anyway. May as well get rid of the middle-man.